# TOP 1 Query from each ID with multiple instances

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

This query will return the top for all rows in MS Access.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [table]
ORDER BY table.[Date] DESC;
```

I need to return the top date for each id that can have multiple dates.

```
ID      DATE
1      01/01/2001
1      01/12/2011
3      01/01/2001
3      01/12/2011
```

Should return only the top dates like this.

```
1      01/12/2011
3      01/12/2011
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use the [MAX function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/min-max-functions-HP001032255.aspx), along with a [GROUP BY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx).

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY ID
```