# Select row with distinct value and max date

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a MySQL (5.1.49) table with three columns.

```
mysql> create table testme(id int auto_increment, id2 int not null, somedate datetime, primary key(id));
```

In my case **id2** is not unique, but I want to return rows with distinct **id2** values with the max **somedate**.

Here's some sample data.

```
mysql> insert into testme values (1, 5, '2012-01-02 01:01:01'),(2, 5, '2012-02-02 02:02:02'),(3, 7, '2010-01-10 11:01:33');
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038980/top-1-query-from-each-id-with-multiple-instances) almost answers mine, but with the extra id field, the returned **id** and **id2** don't match. For **id2=5**, it's returning **id=1** instead of **id=2**.

```
mysql> select id, id2, max(somedate) from testme group by id2;
+----+-----+---------------------+
| id | id2 | max(somedate)       |
+----+-----+---------------------+
|  1 |   5 | 2012-02-02 02:02:02 |
|  3 |   7 | 2010-01-10 11:01:33 |
+----+-----+---------------------+
```

I'm expecting,

```
+----+-----+---------------------+
| id | id2 | max(somedate)       |
+----+-----+---------------------+
|  2 |   5 | 2012-02-02 02:02:02 |
|  3 |   7 | 2010-01-10 11:01:33 |
+----+-----+---------------------+
```

Want the ID that matches maximum date for each ID2

Does anyone have any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query would definitely work, although it may be not the optimal one:

```
select t.id, s.id2, s.somedate 
from testme t 
  join 
    ( select id2, max(somedate) as somedate 
      from testme 
      group by id2
    ) s 
    on  s.id2 = t.id2 
    and s.somedate = t.somedate;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to your problem:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.id2, t0.somedate 
FROM testme AS t0 
LEFT JOIN testme AS t1 
    ON t0.id2 = t1.id2 
    AND t1.somedate > t0.somedate
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

Like @itsmeee solution, if `id2, somedate` pairs are not unique, it will bring both rows:

```
+----+-----+---------------------+
| id | id2 | somedate            |
+----+-----+---------------------+
|  4 |   8 | 2012-02-02 02:02:02 |
|  6 |   8 | 2012-02-02 02:02:02 |
+----+-----+---------------------+
```

If `id2, somedate` pairs are not unique and, for some reason, you need only one result per `id2`, you can let MySQL pick one for you with an extra `GROUP BY t0.id2` clause. But be warned that this is non standard SQL behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When it is about getting the maximum date in a set of record, it is not advisable to combine `max(date)` with other rows. You will always get, of course, the `max(date)` but other fields will be the first occurrence in that set. Here is an answer to your question, using your table as an example:

```
+----+-----+---------------------+
| id | id2 |    somedate         |
+----+-----+---------------------+
|  1 |   5 | 2012-01-02 01:01:01 |
|  2 |   5 | 2012-02-02 02:02:02 |
|  3 |   7 | 2010-01-10 11:01:33 |
+----+-----+---------------------+
```

```
select id, id2, somedate from testme t1
where somedate = 
(select max(somedate) from testme t2 where t2.somedate = t1.somedate) 
order by somedate desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but based on your example, try this:

```
select max(id) as Id,id2,max(someDate) from testMe group by Id2
```

Comment: Same comment than for @triclosan answer. If you execute `INSERT INTO testme (id, id2,somedate) VALUES (4,8,'2012-02-02 02:02:02');
INSERT INTO testme (id, id2, somedate) VALUES (5,8,'2010-01-02 01:01:01');` Your query will return `5, 8, 2012-02-02 02:02:02`.

Comment: True, but I read his example and added a clarification as to what he was trying to accomplish.   Just didn't have time to remove my answer once I realized it wasn't right.    Sorry